# join three tables for nested report

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, window-functions

I am trying to find a way to properly write a query to get the student answers for each question. I am not very good with SQL so I appreciate any help. This is for a student report I am building in PHP/MySQL

Firstly I have a question_table which stores the questions.
structure is:

```
id
question
```

Then I have a student table which has the student details.
structure is

```
id
student_name
```

Then I have an answers table, which contains each question_id and student_id.
structure is:

```
id
question_id
student_id
answer
```

I want to create a report where for each listed question. It shows the answer for each student. Something like:

```
Question: What is the name of the largest planet in the Solar System
Student A: Jupiter
Student B: Jupiter
Student C: Saturn
```

I have tried below but it does not work correctly...:

```
select * from question, student
inner join answer
where answer.question_id = question.id
```

Another challenge is that the report should be paginated. So first 20 questions per page. If a question has multiple student answers then the count will be more and I am not sure how I can paginate this correctly :(

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want two joins. This gives you one row per question/student:

```
select q.question, s.student_name, a.answer
from answers a
inner join questions q on q.id = a.question_id
inner join students s on s.id = a.student_id
order by q.id, s.id
```

You can implement the pagination logic with window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select *
from (
    select q.question, s.student_name, a.answer,
        dense_rank() over(order by q.id) rn
    from answers a
    inner join questions q on q.id = a.question_id
    inner join students s on s.id = a.student_id
) t
where rn between ? and ?
order by q.id, s.id
```

The two question marks represent the range of questions you want. The first question has index `1`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you sir! Can you also take a look at my edited question about pagination?

Comment: Unfortuntately my server is version 5... :(

Answer (score 0):

For pagination logic you have to use `LIMIT` keyword.It's supported to your server version.
Query like :

```
SELECT q.question, s.student_name, a.answer
FROM answers a
INNER JOIN questions q ON q.id = a.question_id
INNER JOIN students s ON s.id = a.student_id
ORDER BY q.id, s.id LIMIT 0,20
```

Now, you will get record 0 to 20.

Using of this you have to specify there are more data for get if yes then call next page and your `LIMIT 20,20`(have to make your own calculation For get offset according to pagination)

If there are no data for next page then stop execute query.